# Why does the program give a mistake?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

```
public class DB {
    String []teacher_name={"Сергей", "Кирилл", "Дмитрий", "Дарья"};
    String []teacher_surname={"Филатов", "Майборода", "Борисов", "Боброва"};
    String []name_subject={"Линейная алгебра", "Программирование 1", "Программирование 2", "Математический анализ"};
    String []emails={"filatovsrg94@gmail.com","emailKirill@mail.ru","borisovsky.n7@live.com","bobrova.94@bk.ru"};

     private static final String DB_NAME = "SCBIdb";
      private static final int DB_VERSION = 14;
      private static final String DB_TABLE = "Teachers";

      public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
      public static final String COLUMN_PH = "img";
      public static final String COLUMN_TNM = "T_name";
      public static final String COLUMN_TSRNM = "T_surname";
      public static final String COLUMN_SUB = "Name_subject";

      private static final String DB_CREATE = 
        "create table " + DB_TABLE + "(" +
          COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
          COLUMN_PH + " integer, " +
          COLUMN_TNM + " text" +
          COLUMN_TSRNM + " text"+
          COLUMN_SUB + " text" +
        ");";

      private final Context mCtx;


      private DBHelper mDBHelper;
      private SQLiteDatabase mDB;

      public DB(Context ctx) {
        mCtx = ctx;
      }

      // открыть подключение
      public void open() {
        mDBHelper = new DBHelper(mCtx, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        mDB = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
      }

      // закрыть подключение
      public void close() {
        if (mDBHelper!=null) mDBHelper.close();
      }

      // получить все данные из таблицы DB_TABLE
      public Cursor getAllData() {
        return mDB.query(DB_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null);
      }

      // добавить запись в DB_TABLE
      public void addRec(String name, String surname, String subject, int img) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COLUMN_TNM, name);
        cv.put(COLUMN_TSRNM, surname);
        cv.put(COLUMN_SUB, subject);
        cv.put(COLUMN_PH, img);
        mDB.insert(DB_TABLE, null, cv);
      }



      // класс по созданию и управлению БД
      private class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DBHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
            int version) {
          super(context, name, factory, version);
        }

        // создаем и заполняем БД
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

          db.execSQL(DB_CREATE);

          ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
          for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
              cv.put(COLUMN_PH, R.drawable.user_sam);
              cv.put(COLUMN_TNM, teacher_name[i]);
              cv.put(COLUMN_TSRNM, teacher_surname[i]);
            cv.put(COLUMN_SUB, name_subject[i]);

            db.insert(DB_TABLE, null, cv);
          }
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '" + DB_TABLE+"'");
            onCreate(db);
        }
      }
    }
```

I try to run the application, but the log says that some fields of the table do not exist. Also i have already made a database in this program before but then i upgraded the version several times. Please, help!

Comment: Post database structure (database dump with create table expressions), and post the exact error message ,  if you  want a usefull answer.

Comment: @Sergey the database had only one table-teachers. And now I am adding 2 more fields (T_name, T_surname).The message: "09-16 14:13:58.481: E/AndroidRuntime(385): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ru.patufedor.scbi/ru.patufedor.scbi.User}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'T_surname' does not exist
"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
      COLUMN_PH + " integer, " +
      COLUMN_TNM + " text" +
      COLUMN_TSRNM + " text"+
      COLUMN_SUB + " text" +
```

You are missing some commas and spaces after your "text"s there. That columns wont be created.
Always make sure you got all commas and whitespaces where they should be, most of the time they are the problem with errors like that.
And as always, uninstall and reinstall the App or increase the database version code after changing.

Comment: @triptop fixed, Thank you! How could i be so inattentive?)

Answer (score 0):

The database column name is "textT_surname",  not "T_surname" , according  to  your code.
you  messed up  with blanks.

Comment: Yes, I have added spaces and commas and everything is fine, thank you!